# problems with regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have the following class that uses regular expressions, valid text correctly according to the expression but when qualifies not let me go to the next component, which is my mistake?

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.swing.InputVerifier;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class VerificarCorreoDAO extends InputVerifier {

    Pattern formato = Pattern.compile("^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,3})$ ");
    Matcher mat;
    String texto;
    JLabel lblMensaje;

    @Override
    public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
        if (input instanceof JTextField) {
            texto = ((JTextField) input).getText().trim();
            if (texto.length() == 0) {                
                return false;
            } else if (texto.length() > 0 && texto.length() < 16 || texto.length() > 50) {                
                return false;
            }
        }
        mat = formato.matcher(texto);
        return mat.matches();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables `mat` and `texto` are instance fields, but you're using them as method variables.  Move them into `verify()`:

```
public class VerificarCorreoDAO extends InputVerifier {

    Pattern formato = Pattern.compile("^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,3})$ ");
    JLabel lblMensaje;

    @Override
    public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
        Matcher mat;
        String texto;
        if (input instanceof JTextField) {
            texto = ((JTextField) input).getText().trim();
            if (texto.length() == 0) {                
                return false;
            } else if (texto.length() > 0 && texto.length() < 16 || texto.length() > 50) {                
                return false;
            }
        }
        mat = formato.matcher(texto);
        return mat.matches();
    }
}
```

Also, your code tries to use `texto` even if it hasn't been set.  That could be a problem.

But the most likely issue here is in the regular expression itself; you have an end-of-input marker `$` *followed by* a space.  There is no possible input that matches that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If the input `Component` is not a `JTextField` then `formato.matcher` will throw a `NPE` preventing the `verify` method from returning `true`. Move the statement inside the `if` block

```
if (input instanceof JTextField) {
        ....

    return formato.matcher(texto).matches();
} else {
  ...// handle other component types
}
```